# How to use replace or a different method to remove/replace the anchor/href tags in this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

So, just to make this a little clearer, this is an array of data that is being passed through state in my react app after using the fetch api. Is there a way for me to use the replace method in my code to replace/remove the strings/tags and only leave the "text" portions of it?

array

```
"array":[{"time":"2019-12-23 21:11:00","cause":"text"},{"time":"2020-01-02 05:44:00","cause":"text"},{"time":"2020-01-02 18:41:00","cause":"text textBC<\/a>."},{"time":"2020-01-11 07:56:00","cause":"text"},{"time":"2020-01-17 07:36:00","cause":"text and some textC<\/a>, textB<\/a>."},{"time":"2020-01-24 03:27:00","cause":"text and some textL<\/a>, textY<\/a>."}]
```

How it's displayed when rendered:

```
Cause: text1 <a href="url">textA</a>, <a href="url">textA</a>.
Cause: text2 <a href="url">textB</a>, <a href="url">textB</a>.
Cause: text3 <a href="url">textC</a>, <a href="url">textC</a>.
Cause: text4 <a href="url">textD</a>, <a href="url">textD</a>.
```

My code:

```
import React from 'react';

    function DisplayFetchedData ( {array= []}) {
            return (
                    <div>
                        {array.map(array => (
                            <div>
                                <h1 className='f4 gray'>Cause: {array.cause}</h1>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
        )
    }

export default DisplayFetchedData;
```

Comment: Please show `array`

Comment: I'll edit the main question with the array

Comment: Try `{array.cause.replace( /(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '')}` instead of `{array.cause}`.

Comment: @Akhil Dude, that worked, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Okay, I will add it as an answer. Please mark it correct so that other people with similar problems can also make use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the tags with a regex. Use something like:

```
{array.cause.replace( /(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '')}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` to get the text before tag like this:

```
Cause: {array.cause.split("<")[0]}
```

Comment: How about also getting the text inside the tags?